# The return type 'Future<Object?>' isn't a 'void', as required by the closure's context

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm receiving this error. Can someone please help me :) ps: I'm new to flutter
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tJNm.png)

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please add the code as text using the Code Sample option in the editor {}, this will be useful to reproduce the code and many other benefits. Also please provide more details about what you've done and want you want to achieve.

Comment: Why do you want to return this line in a ListTile? That doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the "return" statement because "onTap" it's a void function, so it doesn't require a "return", you code might work if you only delete this "return". Furthermore, when you call "pushNamed" from Navigator, it returns a Future, but you don't actually need to take the value from it.

It may help later if you take a peek on [Flutter's documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics#1-create-two-routes).

```dart
 onTap(){
   if(doc!["subCat"] == null)
       Navigator.pushNamed(context, SellerBookForm.id);
  }
```

Comment: Hi.. I tried removing the return statement.. although the code worked and I'm not getting any compile-time error but instead got a run-time error  upon navigating to that page - > NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null. Tried calling : length

Comment: Where are you calling the "length"method in your code? Probably, it's a null-safety problem.

Comment: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
future: _service.categories.doc(args.id).get(),
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {return Container();}
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);}
            var data = snapshot.data!['subCat'];
            return Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){return Padding();

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to add `return` at the time of navigation. just call-

```
Navigator.pushName(context,"YourRouteName");
```